# Taking the most recent value from a range of columns for new variable

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
df_test<- data.frame(id = c("1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a"),
                     baseline= c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1),
                     checkin1= c(0,NA,1, 2, NA, NA,NA, 1, NA, NA),
                     checkin2= c(-1,NA, NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                     checkin3= c(-1, 0, 1,1,1,2,2,NA,NA,2),
                     checkin4= c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1))
```

I am trying to make a new column that takes the most "recent" (`checkin4` being the most recent, `checkin1` being the oldest) non-NA value from columns 3:6 (checkin1:checkin4). For rows where there are no non-NA values (row 9), the new column value would be NA. So, the result that I am looking for is:

```
result<- data.frame(id = c("1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a"),
                     baseline= c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1),
                     checkin1= c(0,NA,1, 2, NA, NA,NA, 1, NA, NA),
                     checkin2= c(-1,NA, NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                     checkin3= c(-1, 0, 1,1,1,2,2,NA,NA,2),
                     checkin4= c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
                    end= c(-1,0,1,2,1,2,2,1,NA,1))
```

I'm sure I could do this with a combination of `ifelse` and `mutate` but am hoping there is a more direct way of getting to this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr::coalesce()` is great for that.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_test |> 
  mutate(end = coalesce(checkin4, checkin3, checkin2, checkin1))
#>     id baseline checkin1 checkin2 checkin3 checkin4 end
#> 1   1a       -1        0       -1       -1       NA  -1
#> 2   2a       -1       NA       NA        0       NA   0
#> 3   3a       -1        1       NA        1       NA   1
#> 4   4a       -1        2        4        1        2   2
#> 5   5a       -1       NA       NA        1       NA   1
#> 6   6a       -1       NA       NA        2       NA   2
#> 7   7a       -1       NA       NA        2       NA   2
#> 8   8a       -1        1       NA       NA       NA   1
#> 9   9a       -1       NA       NA       NA       NA  NA
#> 10 10a       -1       NA       NA        2        1   1
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!